# How to use the GetPixel function in a Windows Phone App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I can't use the `GetPixel` function in my Windows Phone App. It gives me an error:

```
'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not
contain a definition for 'GetPixel' and no extension method 'GetPixel'
accepting a first argument of type
'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' could be found (are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Step 1: Read and understand this - http://stackoverflow.com/tour
Step 2: Edit this question

Comment: Post your code. We are not magicians and cannot read your mind.

Comment: look into the nuget package `WriteablebitmapEx`, I'm pretty sure it has a `WritePixel`

Answer (score 1):

The `GetPixel` function is a member of the class `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. Whereas you are using `System.Media.WriteableBitmap`. Source : MSDN - [Bitmap.GetPixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).